# Failed to instantiate module Error: [$injector:unpr]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is my script.js code:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', [])

app.provider('RouteHelpers', function () {

    this.basepath = function (uri) {
        return 'app/views/' + uri;
    };

    this.$get = function () {
    };

}); 

app.config(function (RouteHelpers) {
    console.log('Never gets here');
});
```

And this is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">


<script src="angular.min.js"></script>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app='starter'>


  </body>
</html>
```

And I'm getting this error in my browser: https://tinyurl.com/nbareaa
Does someone have an idea what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a provider, which means if you try and inject it into your config function you must append `Provider` to the end of the providers name, for example:

```
app.config(function(RouteHelpersProvider){

});
```

You are getting the error because it cannot find the given injector. You can read more [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) under provider recipe.